# How do I destroy a pirate haven?

Tags: imperator-rome

One of my provinces contains a pirate haven, that regularly spawns pirate fleets.

Can I destroy these old seadogs and feed them to the fishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure your law is set to anti piracy, for Rome that's "Lex Claudia" [image: Lex Claudia]
2. Move a land army to the location of the pirate haven.
3. Set the army's stance to "Root out pirates" (it's the icon on the bottom right of the stances selection area). This will cost a base of 100 military power.

   [image: root our pirates]

Your army will force the pirates to walk the plank and and the haven will be gone forever.